# Using sequential observations to perform online prediction

Tags: time-series, machine-learning, distributions, predictive-models, markov-process

I'm trying to perform predictions from a sequence of events. My problem is this:

**Data collection:**

Suppose you can continuously observe a person sitting in a library. You take note of every time that the person checks his smartphone, goes to the restroom, or is reading. At some point after several hours, the person then gets up and leaves. Assume that you can do this for several days to get a lot of data.

**Problems to be solved:**

Now, suppose I can perform observations only at sparse discrete points in time (e.g. once every 10 or 20 minutes). I would like to perform online (in real-time, with a short window) the following two computations:

Given a sequence of sparse online observations of either (a) using smartphone, (b) going to restroom, or (c) reading, I would like to know the probability that the user will next be reading for more than t minutes. For example, if the user has a habit of checking his smartphone and then starts reading uninterrupted for 20 minutes, then if I make an online observation that he is indeed checking his smartphone, then I would say that the probability he will read for more than 10 minutes is, say, 0.90. I would as few needed observations as possible.

If I want to determine when the user will get up and leave within the next t minutes with some threshold probability, how would I schedule the minimal number of needed observations?

I have been reading up on Markov chains, HMMs, and random walks, but my problem seems to be a bit different from what I've read.

Any help would be appreciated.